# DataGridView not saving to database

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, insert, sql-insert

I am creating a simple staff directory program, and I am making it so the user can update the directory. However, at current time when adding data into the DataGridView, it does not save to the database. I understand that `this.staffTableAdapter.Update(this.dBDataSet1.Staff);` is needed, which is in my program as you will see below.

I'm just not sure what I am missing at the moment, and would be greatful if anyone could help me out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StaffDirectory
{
    public partial class Administration : Form
    {
        public Administration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void staffBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.staffBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.staffTableAdapter.Update(this.dBDataSet1.Staff);
        }

        private void Administration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dBDataSet1.Staff' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.staffTableAdapter.Fill(this.dBDataSet1.Staff);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no exceptions there?

Comment: sometimes it's possible that you work whit a copy of your database. be sure that you don't work whit one. You can check it by the properties of your database. I'm not sure that you do it.

Comment: I have created a dataset from my database, what does 'whit' mean in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `try-catch` block and analyze/provide us with the exception description (`ex.Message`):

```
private void staffBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try{
       this.Validate();
       this.staffBindingSource.EndEdit();
       this.staffTableAdapter.Update(this.dBDataSet1.Staff);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {}
}
```

Also, add `this.dBDataSet1.Staff.AcceptChanges()`; (re: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ceab2k93.aspx)

Hope this may help. Best regards,